# On the Cyclic Subgroups

Tags: group-theory

I recently read in a book on group theory that, a (non-abelian) $2$-generator group all of whose proper subgroups are cyclic, has been constructed by Ol`sanski; these are infinite simple groups. (see Groups '93 GalwaySt Andrews vol. 2, p.389). Can anybody give structure of the group here, and certain lower dimensional matrix representation of the group? (I mean, viewing group as group of matrices over some ring/field,..).

Also, are there non-abelian groups of similar type, where all proper subgroups are infinite cyclic?

(I couldn't see this group (means I know only the existance, beliving onOl'sanski), I couldn't see also the paper in which it is given, due to accessibility of journals. I like to know what is this group; one can write here it in terms of generators and relations or as a group of matrices etc.)

Comment: I think you are out of luck! The Tarski Monsters do not have any nontrivial finite dimensional representations over any commutative ring, and they do not have finite presentations.

Answer (score 2):

This group (s) is (are) also called [Tarski Monster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group) : it's a simple non-abelian group generated by two elements with the rather astonishing property that any non-trivial subgroup is finite, cyclic and of order a given, fixed prime $\;p\;$ .

For sure these groups exist for prime $\,p>10^{75}\,$ , and as far as I know this bound hasn't been improved greatly in the last 34 years.